# How can isDirty function be implemented in angular using JSON.stringify()?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I would like to implement an is dirty property using JSON.stringify(model). I have an initial model. that can be serialized to a string using the following:

```
original:string;

setModel(model:any) { 
    // serialize the model
    this.original = JSON.stringify(model);
    this.model = model;
} 

get isDirty() :boolean 
{ 
    // check if model has changed.
    return JSON.stringify(this.model) != this.original;
}
```

This works for a simple property on the model being changed like

```
model.name = "My name is Slim Shady"!
```

However, the following doesn't update result isDirty() to true:

```
model.members.push({name:"Slim Shady"});
```

How might I implement this so isDirty is checked for both scenarios?

Comment: It should definitely update it. You're doing something else wrong. Also what are you trying to achieve? There must be a better way.

Comment: I added these two buttons as a test.   <button (click)="model.name='hello'">Say Hello</button>
  <button (click)="model.categories.push({ description: 'hello'})">Add</button> but only the Say Hello want updates my dirty flag {{ isDirty }} in the user interface. However, the part of the UI does add the extra category in a for loop.

Comment: I just want to check if my object graph has changed to show a save button.

Comment: I think `.push` will not trigger change detection. Try with `(click)=pushToModel()` and `pushToModel() { this.model.categories.push({ description: 'hello'}); this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();}`. But you should probably be using some kind of reactive forms which have built-in `isDirty` functionality.

Comment: I already tried using the ChangeDetectionRef to no avail. I will try again just to prove myself wrong.

Comment: Post a mvce so I can test it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/10vs36mh/ It works in the example so I'll have to take a closer look.

Comment: Btw, I think stackblitz is better for making online Angular snippets, you should try it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2j9fe3

Comment: Thanks, there was an unexpected error that caused it so worked as expected after all.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out!